# How to access remote Object

Tags: java

I'm new to Java. I want to create Java Object with test data and access the object from remote class. I created this object:

```
public class TestAgentData
{

    public TestAgentDataObj tad;

    public class TestAgentDataObj
    {

        public int agentId = 1234;
        public String agentName = "AgentName";
        public String description = "AgentDscription";

        public TestAgentDataObj(int agentId, String agentName, String description)
        {
            this.agentId = agentId;
            this.agentName = agentName;
            this.description = description;
        }

        public int getAgentId()
        {
            return agentId;
        }

        public void setAgentId(int agentId)
        {
            this.agentId = agentId;
        }

        public String getAgentName()
        {
            return agentName;
        }

        public void setAgentName(String agentName)
        {
            this.agentName = agentName;
        }

        public String getDescription()
        {
            return description;
        }

        public void setDescription(String description)
        {
            this.description = description;
        }
    }

    public TestAgentDataObj getTad()
    {
        return tad;
    }

    public void setTad(TestAgentDataObj tad)
    {
        this.tad = tad;
    }
}
```

I tried to access the object from remote class:

Object eded = new TestAgentData.getTad();

But I get error in Netbeans. Can you tell what is the proper way to access data in a Java Object?

Comment: Apparently you really don't understand the very basics of Java or OOP. A good beginner's book or the Oracle tutorials would be a better place to start instead of typing / copy-pasting random things into your computer and expecting them to work.

Comment: i though that remote class were in another part not in the same prject xD

Comment: TestAgentData eded = new TestAgentData().getTad();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a better understanding about java. There are big errors in this.
You cannot way you create your object is wrong its `new TestAgentData()`

You can't call getTad() from an object of type `Object` because there is no `getTad()` method defined in Object class. Rather do the following

```
TestAgentDataObj obj=new TestAgentData().new TestAgentDataObj();
TestAgentData eded = new TestAgentData();
eded.setTad(obj);
TestAgentDataObj result=eded.getTad();
```

Comment: And then the OP's next question will be "Why does that return `null`?" (Or actually, why he gets an NPE when he tries to use `eded` in any way)

Comment: what he wanted was to access the data. That is why I only included 'getTad()' if he tries to use that it will definitely get NPE. so you first need to call 'setTad()' obviously.

Comment: Anyway i will edit my answer with setter method also.